# Instance Variable in Java

Tags: java

If we change the value of instance variable in a method then will it change for all methods or is it locally affected?
For Ex

```
public class A
{
  public int X() //first function
  { 
    p=2;
  }
  public int Y() //second function
  {
    p=3;
  }
  println(p);
  public int p;
  //instance variable
}
```

Comment: It changes for the whole object, so yes, everywhere.  What would be the point otherwise?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You might want to start with code that actually compiles. Then you can just, you know, run it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, instance variables and instance methods are belongs to objects of the class. So, when you change an instance variable, it affect the object. It will reflect whereever you are using that object.